# Using SSL from a CA for server + allowing ssl client authorization that is self-signed with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate

First time working with SSL client authentication. The way it works with node.js while mixing with a certificate issued by a third-party CA (in this case it is StartSSL) is confusing me.

On production servers I'm using nginx as load balancer to different node.js instances. Since this is how I had done it before, nginx is handling all the HTTPS work and then passing a plain http request to a node instance. Since it has been deciding to always enforce SSL (for all kind of requests, using HSTS and using simple redirects), I'm considering the possibility to moving into having nginx doing only the balancing and letting the nodejs instances take care of the rest.

So, what I ignore is how to handle this with Node.js?

I found this blog post http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2012/06/securing-nodejs-and-express-with-ssl.html and this other http://blog.nategood.com/nodejs-ssl-client-cert-auth-api-rest

What I don't understand is how to handle both SSL authentications simultaneously. I hope I'm making some sense.

The idea is to generate a certificate for each user which has a CN that I match to a user, then ask for a password that, after bcrypted, should match what is on the database. While, at the same time, using the verification level 3 certificate that works with the CA to improve our users' safety.

Comment: The client cert does not need to be issued from the same authority as the server's SSL cert.  You can provide your own CA in the `ca` array to validate the requested client cert.

Comment: Got it :) I hadn't really understood how it worked and I got confused. Thanks!